# SQL query - select distinct category and count

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

I am working on a SQL query where I select distinct category and count how many rows in x category. I want to achieve a result like:

```
X.category | Amount
--------------------
Hi         | 3
--------------------
Hello      | 2
--------------------
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT company.category,  category.desc2 FROM company, category
```

This query works but lacks amount (count).

Comment: google and learn about the GROUP BY clause in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I think I have come up with a solution to my own problem.

```
SELECT DISTINCT company.category, count(DISTINCT company.id) as amount, category.name, category.desc2 FROM company, category WHERE company.category = category.name GROUP BY company.category;
```

Comment: you should drop the pre Ansi syntax and use a JOIN. its better because you can do more with it.. if you want an example I can write an answer out.. but a count(distinct) is the way to go for something like this

Answer (score 0):

I think the code your looking for is the `GROUP BY`-clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT company.category, COUNT(*) 
FROM company, category
GROUP BY company.category
```

You can read more about in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT  company.category,  count(*) FROM company, category
Where company.category=Category.category
Group By company.category
```